# What does it mean "to channel" somebody?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> The director Bryan Singer clearly enjoys playing with these oversize, puppetlike meanies and finds queasy comedy in their threat, especially when Jack, Isabelle and some others, including a knight, Elmont (Ewan McGregor **channeling** Errol Flynn), nearly become finger food.

*Source: "This Jack stays near the stalk", THE GLOBAL EDITION OF THE NEW YORK TIMES, THURSDAY, MARCH 7, 2013*

What does it mean "to channel" somebody? Does it mean to imitate?

Comment: [to behave like or copy another person, so that you almost seem to be that other person](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/channel)

Answer (score 3):

In this context [channel](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=channel) means to act like another person.

> to invoke the style or characteristics of another person

You might see it in more fantastic settings being used to describe allowing the spirit or ghost of a deceased person to speak or act through the first individual's body.

In this case the excerpt is using it in a much more common metaphorical way.